# Some issue in node.js fs.createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, fs

This code seems behave Ok, but when I try read  the file (someFile.json) in the last line simply does not work. :-( Please some clue. Although I know the issue is complex.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var request = require("request")


var dataFile = 'data/someFile.json'
var url = "https://api.someUrl"
var file = fs.createWriteStream(dataFile);
request(url).pipe(file);

file.on('finish',function(){
    console.log('file download to ',dataFile)
    file.destroy();
    //file.closeSync;
    file.on('close', function(){ console.log('File Closed ')})
})


var datos = fs.readFileSync(dataFile, 'utf8');
```

Comment: Node is **asynchronous**. The last line will be executed before the file is finished writing. If you put it inside the callback to `file.on`, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read the file BEFORE it has been written.  The writeStream you are writing to is asynchronous.  That means it completes some indeterminate time in the future.  Meanwhile, the rest of your code continues to run and thus you try to read it before the file has been finished.

In the code you have, here's the sequence of events.

1. Create writeStream
2. Initiate http `request()`
3. Hook future data arriving from the `request()` to your stream with `.pipe()`.
4. Register `finish` event handler on the stream.
5. Call `fs.readFileSync()` to read the file
6. Data arrives from `request()` and is sent to the write stream where it may be buffered.
7. More data arrives from `request()` and is sent to the write stream where it may be buffered.
8. Request finishes, telling the writeStream to flush its data to disk and close itself.
9. The `finish` event occurs.
10. You register a `close` event handler.
11. The `close` event occurs.

---

You can likely use stream notifications to do what you want, but to just test out the file, you can put the `fs.readFileSync()` in the completion handle for the close event on the write stream.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require("request")

const dataFile = 'data/someFile.json'
const url = "https://api.someUrl"
const file = fs.createWriteStream(dataFile);
request(url).pipe(file);

file.on('finish',function(){
    console.log('file download to ',dataFile)
}).on('close', function(){ 
   console.log('File Closed ');
   // file is available for reading now
   var datos = fs.readFileSync(dataFile, 'utf8');    
   console.log(datos);
});
```

Also, you do not need to `.destroy()` the stream.  By default, it will be set to `autoClose` which will close automatically when the stream you piped to it is done.  And, you do not want your `.on('close', ...)` event handler inside your `finish` error handler.

In this new suggested code, here's the sequence of events:

1. Create writeStream
2. Initiate http `request()`
3. Hook future data arriving from the `request()` to your stream with `.pipe()`.
4. Register `finish` event handler on the stream.
5. Register `close` event handler.
6. Data arrives from `request()` and is sent to the write stream where it may be buffered.
7. More data arrives from `request()` and is sent to the write stream where it may be buffered.
8. Request finishes, telling the writeStream to flush its data to disk and close itself.
9. The `finish` event occurs.
10. The `close` event occurs.
11. Call `fs.readFileSync()` to read the file

Answer (score 0):

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    
    var request = require("request")

    function writeStreamToFile(filePath, stream) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filePath))
        stream.on('close', () => {
          // File ready to read
          resolve()
        })
        stream.on('finish', () => {
          // Download complete
          console.log('Download Complete')
        })
        stream.on('error', (error: any) => {
          reject(error)
      }

    })
    
    var dataFile = 'data/someFile.json'
    var url = "https://api.someUrl"
    var response = await request(url)

    var err = await writeStreamToFile(dataFile, response.data)      
    
    if(!err)
      var datos = fs.readFileSync(dataFile, 'utf8');
```